# Can I buy a Context Menu control for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, components, contextmenu

I've been looking for a ContextMenu control for Silverlight.  There is one from Microsoft, but it's severely crippled (you can't add/remove things at runtime, does not support submenus, etc...)

I've looked at the commercial components from Telerik, ComponentOne, Infragistics, etc...  and they provide the features I am looking for, but they only sell the ContextMenu component as a part of their larger suite (in excess of $1000).

Can anyone recommend a reasonably priced ContextMenu control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it on codeplex.  It's actually pretty awesome.  http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com/